# How to change icon size in MUI breakpoints?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, responsive, breakpoints

```
import { Container } from "@mui/material";
import * as React from "react";
import { Home } from "@mui/icons-material";
import PersonIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Person";
import FormatListBulletedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/FormatListBulleted";
import CameraAltIcon from "@mui/icons-material/CameraAlt";
import OndemandVideoIcon from "@mui/icons-material/OndemandVideo";
import PhoneAndroidIcon from "@mui/icons-material/PhoneAndroid";
import FeaturedPlayListIcon from "@mui/icons-material/FeaturedPlayList";
import StorefrontIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Storefront";
import SettingsIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Settings";
import LogoutIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Logout";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";

const StyledContainer = styled("div")(({ theme }) => ({
  paddingTop: theme.spacing(10),
  backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
  height: "100vh",
  color: "white",
  [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
    backgroundColor: "white",
    color: "#555",
    border: "1px solid #ece7e7",
  },
}));

const Item = styled("div")(({ theme }) => ({
  display: "flex",
  alignItems: "center",
  marginBottom: theme.spacing(4),
  [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(3),
    cursor: "Pointer",
  },
}));

const Icon = styled("div")(({ theme }) => ({
  marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
  [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
    //I need to change the Icon size
    //fontSize:"18px" but this not working
  },
}));

const Text = styled("div")(({ theme }) => ({
  fontWeight: 500,
  fontSize: "300px",
  [theme.breakpoints.down("sm")]: {
    display: "none",
  },
}));

function Leftbar() {
  return (
    <StyledContainer>
      <Container>
        <div>
          <Item>
            <Icon>
              <Home />
            </Icon>
            <Text>
              <Typography>Homepage</Typography>
            </Text>
          </Item>
        </div>
        <div>
          <Item>
            <Icon>
              <PersonIcon />
            </Icon>
            <Text>
              <Typography>Friends</Typography>
            </Text>
          </Item>
        </div>
      </Container>
    </StyledContainer>
  );
}

export default Leftbar;
```

This is my sidebar code. and this is the screenshot of the page.

[image]

Here I need to change the sidebar icon sizes. But the problem is I unable to change the Icon sizes in breakpoints. This is the code of that breakpoint.

```
 const Icon = styled("div")(({ theme }) => ({
      marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
      [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
        //I need to change the Icon size
        //fontSize:"18px" but this not working
      },
    }));
```

I tried several times to solve this problem. But I didn't get a solution. So if anyone knows how to solve this problem, Please help me. Thank you

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select svg to apply font size.
Try this

```js
[theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
    '& svg': {
      fontSize: 18
    }
},
```

Comment: If I have an image instead of an icon, how would it be done?

Comment: For an img you need to set width & height properties

Comment: I need to change the image size in CardMedia in the Card. So what can I do?

Comment: I updated my question with new screenshot of my code

Comment: In here, I need to change image size with CardImage

Comment: Please create new question for it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sure. I will Ask

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73318191/how-i-can-change-the-image-size-in-mui-card