# How I can change the Image size in MUI Card

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, responsive, card

```
import {
  Card,
  CardActionArea,
  CardContent,
  CardMedia,
  Typography,
} from "@mui/material";
import React from "react";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";

const CardImage = styled("div")(({ theme }) => ({
  marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
  height: 250,
}));

function Post() {
  return (
    <Card>
      <CardActionArea>
        <CardImage>
          <CardMedia
            image="https://images.pexels.com/photos/12977998/pexels-photo-12977998.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1"
            title="My Post"
            //   sx={{ height: 250 }}
          />
        </CardImage>
        <CardContent>
          <Typography variant="h5">My First Post</Typography>
          <Typography variant="body">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero
            eaque ducimus maxime expedita, blanditiis explicabo recusandae
            nostrum provident sed accusantium ut repellendus dolore voluptatum
            consequuntur harum. Exercitationem porro provident nulla?
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </CardActionArea>
    </Card>
  );
}

export default Post;
```

This is the output of this code.
[image]

I need to change the image size on this Card. For that I created CardImage. But the problem is that height I entered is not affect the image size. So how can I solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

try to replace **CardMedia** with :

```
<CardMedia
component='img'
image="https://images.pexels.com/photos/12977998/pexels-photo-12977998.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1"
title="My Post"
sx={{ height: 250 }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<CardMedia
component="img"
height="250"
src={imgSource}
alt="alt_text"
/>
```